# Is there a way to dynamically `alt` an iterator of parsers?

Tags: rust, nom

I'm looking to create a function like `alt` that instead of consuming parsers from a tuple, it consumes parsers from an iterator.

The trouble I'm having is with the bound `FnMut` on the parameterized parsers.
`Parser` is implemented for `FnMut`, but not `Fn`.
`FnMut` is not cloneable, which means I have to put it in a `Box` of some sort and then mutably borrow from it.

Here is the signature I would start off with:

```rust
use nom::{Parser,error::ParseError};

fn alt<I, O, E, P>(parsers: impl IntoIterator<Item = P>) -> impl Parser<I, O, E>
where
    P: Parser<I, O, E>
{
    move |input| {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

This implementation works, but only when everything is mutable:

```
use nom::{error::ParseError, InputIter, InputTake, Parser};

pub fn alt_many<I, O, E, P>(mut parsers: Vec<&mut P>) -> impl Parser<I, O, E> + '_
where
    P: Parser<I, O, E>,
    I: InputIter + InputTake + Copy,
    E: ParseError<I>,
{
    move |mut input| {
        use nom::bytes::complete::take;
        use nom::combinator::fail;

        let mut value: Option<O> = None;

        for parser in &mut parsers {
            if let Ok((input_, o)) = parser.parse(input) {
                input = input_;
                value = Some(o);
                break;
            } else {
                (input, _) = take::<u8, I, E>(1)(input)?;
            };
        }

        value
            .map(|output| Ok((input, output)))
            .unwrap_or_else(|| fail::<I, O, E>(input))
    }
}
```

Are there any other possible solutions available?

Comment: Why do you `take(1)` in the else branch, that's not how `alt` would behave.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the actual behavior of `alt` instead of your different one with the `take` you can write `alt_many` like this:

```rust
pub fn alt_many<I, O, E, P, Ps>(mut parsers: Ps) -> impl Parser<I, O, E>
where
    P: Parser<I, O, E>,
    I: Clone,
    for<'a> &'a mut Ps: IntoIterator<Item = &'a mut P>,
    E: ParseError<I>,
{
    move |input: I| { 
        for parser in &mut parsers {
            if let r@Ok(_) = parser.parse(input.clone()) {
                return r;
            }
        }
        nom::combinator::fail::<I, O, E>(input)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be done without cloning the input? Does the error returned from `parse` contain the input so that it can be reused?

Comment: @BallpointBen, the user of this function decides the type of error `E` they want to return, it might contain `input` or it might not `()` is a valid error type, we can't use that to get the `input`. Also in most cases it's a cheap copy of a `&str` or `&[u8]` anyways.